# Ошбика при использовании typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

Здравствуй, стэк! Недавно хотел протестировать код в книге, но у меня есть проблема с использованием typedef.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef long double C;
typedef complex<C> P;
#define X real()
#define Y imag()

using namespace std;

int main(){
    P p = {1, 2};
    P b = {2, 3};
    cout << p.X << ' '  << p.Y;
}
```

Компилятор матерится на строку typedef complex P;
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте-ка

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std;
```

после

```
#include <iostream>
```

а то он у вас не только на `typedef` матерится...

См. https://ideone.com/Kclgo3